# Automatically Delete table rows after reaching row limit and add new data to the row using the Websocket data with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, real-time-updates, real-time-data

I am new to JavaScript, not sure if this very basic question. I've created a Bitcoin Price update dashboard using the data fetched from the external WebSocket. I managed to get the data from the WebSocket and display it on the HTML table. The price updates every seconds, So the table rows are going insane. I want to limit the Table row for 14 rows and after the table get 14 rows i want to delete that data and import new data with the Websocket without increasing the HTML table rows. I tried my best to explain.

I have provided the code snippets below as well as external Websocket from where I am pulling the data.

Please let me know how should I insert the row dynamically into a HTML table. Thank you so much in advance

```
    <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            function insertRow(price){
  var tr      = document.createElement("tr"),
      tdCoin  = document.createElement("td"),
      tdPrice = document.createElement("td"),
      docFrag = new DocumentFragment();
  tdCoin.textContent = "BTC";
  tdPrice.textContent = `${Number(price.slice(0,-6)).toLocaleString("en-US")}`;
  tr.appendChild(tdCoin);
  tr.appendChild(tdPrice);
  docFrag.appendChild(tr);
  return docFrag;
}

var binanceSocket = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade"),
    table = document.getElementById("pricetable");
binanceSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
  var messageObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
  table.appendChild(insertRow(messageObject.p));
}
}
        
    </script>  


<table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Coin</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                                          </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="pricetable" class="crypt-table-hover">

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: Someone please help me with this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all rows in your table using `querySelectorAll("tr")`. You can remove elements from your table using `removeChild`.

So, to make sure your table never grows past `x` rows, you do:

```js
const rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
if (rows.length > 14) table.removeChild(rows[0]);
```

Here's a working example:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  function insertRow(price) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr"),
      tdCoin = document.createElement("td"),
      tdPrice = document.createElement("td"),
      docFrag = new DocumentFragment();
    tdCoin.textContent = "BTC";
    tdPrice.textContent = `${Number(price.slice(0,-6)).toLocaleString("en-US")}`;
    tr.appendChild(tdCoin);
    tr.appendChild(tdPrice);
    docFrag.appendChild(tr);
    return docFrag;
  }

  var binanceSocket = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade"),
    table = document.getElementById("pricetable");
  binanceSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
    var messageObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
    table.appendChild(insertRow(messageObject.p));
    
    const MAX_ROWS = 5;
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
    if (rows.length > MAX_ROWS) table.removeChild(rows[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Coin</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="pricetable" class="crypt-table-hover">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's Working Thank you!!!! Means a lot <3